# What is this place with 5 altars in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

While running like a crazy person around (I tend to do that) I walk upon this place (sorry for low quality... phone pictures) in south east, near the Nilfgaardian border:

[image: world map]

[image: 5 altars]

It looks like a semicircle of 5 altars of some sort, each altar having a symbol on him (swallow, sea monster, dog, mare, and another bird). Looks important/fun but is nothing around (they don't glow on witcher senses, can't interact with them).

From what I remember my first playthrough didn't get me here (but that was like 2+ years ago so I may be wrong) so I don't think is related to the main quest.

So... what is this place? Anything here? My guess is that is not just for flavor but...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/4nml6m/anyone_know_the_solution_to_this_stone_puzzle_at/) Reddit thread, those 5 pillars do not have any functional purpose in The Witcher 3 but serve as a reference to a quest from the first Witcher game

> This spot is a reference to one of the quests in the first Witcher game. In it you had to activate an elemental that was frozen in the middle of five pillars, by convincing the nearby druids to create a thunderstorm so you could use a lightning rod to activate each pillar then fight the elemental

Comment: Ah... yeah I remember the quest. Although I don't remember any symbols on the pillars in W1 (still... I played W1 like 10 years ago so... who remembers if they had symbols or not :P).

Comment: There should in fact have been an elemental there. I recall it being way powerful when I first found it - I think I was around level 15 and decided to go question mark hunting.